# Laravel- How to "catch" a variable with Javascript passed to a blade.php view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-blade

so i'm currently working on a project and i want to add a calendar to one view, i'm using FullCalendar, the calendar is shown in the view but i'm currently trying to add events to that calendar, those events are going to be "pulled" from my database into the calendar to be displayed, now the problem is that when i pass the array with the events to the blade.php view that contains the calendar a error comes up saying that the variable "events" is undefined and i don't know if i'm doing something wrong, here's the code:

RegisteredUserController.php

```
$events = array();
        $citas = Cita::all();
        foreach($citas as $cita){
            $events[] = [
                'title' => $cita->paciente_id,
                'start' => $cita->hora_de_inicio,
                'end' => $cita->hora_de_finalizacion
            ];
        }

return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with(['events' => $events]);
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

homeView.blade.php (**This is where i get the error, in the line where i assign it to citas**)

```
<div id="calendar">

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var citas = @json($events);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
                },
                events: citas
            })
        });
    </script>
```

routes / web.php

```
Route::get('/home', function (){
    return view('homeView');
})->name('homeView');
```

Not sure if it's helpful but i'm using Laravel's Breeze to handle the authentication of users, so when an user is aunthenticated they're redirected to the page where the calendar is.

i've tried the following

RegisteredUserController.php

```
return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME, compact('events));
```

This one makes the whole calendar disappear:

homeView.blade.php

```
var citas = {{ Session::get('events') }};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of fullCalendar? You appear to be using version 3 or earlier. v6 was just released and has many more features, performance improvements, bug fixes etc. If you're just starting to use fullcalendar, use the latest version. https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc

Comment: @ADyson i've actually never worked with FullCalendar before, i was following a Youtube tutorial so i just followed those steps, i guess they were using that version of FullCalendar, but thanks for letting me know, i'll update to the latest version :)

Answer (score 1):

the return should be like this

```
return view('path_of_the_blade', compact('events'));
```

So then in View, you can use

```
<script>
    var citas = @json($events);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On you controller, why don't you just simply use:

```
return view('homeView')->with(['events' => $events]);
```

or simplier:

```
return view('homeView', compact('events'));
```

This would surely pass the variable `events` on the blade file.

Then on your blade file, you will just reference it as:

```
var citas = {{ $events }};
```